# How to execute more than one Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I have a problem here, I want to process some retrofit to get some data and insert it into an ArrayList

Before this I do it with execute 1st retrofit to get 1st data and placing this into Arraylist, if this process done I call the another retrofit to get 2nd data and add this to Arraylist before. and I do this 4 times to get full data.
This is the json data:

The example parameter for 4 request:

```
{"type":"search","block":"A","date":"2015-02-12","subblock":"1"}
{"type":"search","block":"B","date":"2015-02-12","subblock":"5"}
{"type":"search","block":"C","date":"2015-02-12","subblock":"3"}
{"type":"search","block":"D","date":"2015-02-12","subblock":"7"}
```

And the response is same for all 4 request

```
{
  "code":"00",
  "value":[
       {
            "data1":"data1",
            "data2":"data2",
            ... 
       },
       {
            "data1":"data1",
            "data2":"data2",
            ... 
       },
       ...
   ]
}
```

but if I execute it 1 by 1, it takes more time,,
So I want to execute 4 retrofit at the same time and place it to an Arraylist,,

Is there any way to doing that?

Some code or reference for this cases maybe can very helpfull? thanks

**Request My Code :**

```
public void getBlockData(){

    String blockType = "";

    switch (blockIndicator) {
        case 1:
            blockType = "A";
            break;
        case 2:
            blockType = "B";
            break;
        case 3:
            blockType = "C";
            break;
        case 4:
            blockType = "D";
            break;
    }

    ApiConnection.getBlockList(getApplicationContext(), new BlockListListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFlightResponseSuccess(ArrayList<Block> blocks) {
            if (getApplicationContext() != null) {
                if (blocks != null) {
                    try {
                        blockArrayList.addAll(blocks);
                        Collections.sort(blockArrayList);
                        BlockAdapter blockAdapter = new BlockAdapter(getApplicationContext(), blockArrayList);
                        listBlock.setAdapter(blockAdapter);
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, new OnLoadingProgressBar() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStart(String loadingString) {
            progressBarBlock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textBlockLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingStop() {
            progressBarBlock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            textBlockLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            listBlock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            blockIndicator = blockIndicator + 1;
            if (blockIndicator < 5) {
                getBlockList();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please post your request code with retrofit.

Comment: Sorry I can't post all my code,, there's too much code to post,, I have edit my post with my main method to get data,, that ApiConnection.getBlockList is the normal retrofit method to get data,,